# Alter code to get all posts and show in dropdown list, right kown gets only 5 posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I know little about php I have tryed to puzzel my way throught this but have not got any where.

I need this dropdown list show all posts right now it shows only 5 posts.

Thank you

Edit: This is the only other bit of code

```
ob_start();
class externalUrlToPostThumbnail
{
function externalUrlToPostThumbnail(){            
    try{
        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'ext_add_pages'));
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Caught Exception".$e->getMessage();
    }
}
// action function for above hook
function ext_add_pages(){
    add_menu_page(__('Post Featured','mymenu'), __('Featured Image','mymenu'), 'manage_options',  'external-url-post-thumbnail', array ( & $this,'uploadImage'));
}

function uploadImage(){
    include_once('external-url-to-post-thumbnail.php');
}

function get_all_post()
{

    $options_pages = array();
    $options_pages_obj = get_posts('post_type=post');
    $options_pages[''] = 'Select a Post:';  
    foreach ($options_pages_obj as $page) {
    $options_pages[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;  
    }
    return $options_pages;
}   
}
$newObj = new externalUrlToPostThumbnail();
?>
```

Comment: Which CMS/Framework are you using?

Comment: @JohnnyDew I'm pretty sure it's WordPress. Tim, where do you fetch the posts? Specifically, where does `$options_pages` come from?

Comment: That's what I was also thinking, but I just wanted to be sure. You have to define the number of elements you want in your query that is getting your posts. You should have the value `'numberposts' => -1,` in your arguments.

Comment: The question is tagged with WordPress. ;)

Comment: @Fleshgrinder - that tag was added by Alexander.

Comment: Well, I guess @AlexanderO'Mara was really *pretty sure* then. :P

Comment: Hello all and thank you for your input.  Yes it is `wordpress`, appologies for not stating that upfront. I am not sure how to alter the query as @JonnyDew sugests somthing like `<?php foreach($options_pages  as $id=>$value&'numberposts' => -1) :?>`?

Comment: @Tim No, it needs to go where the posts are queried. Where is `$options_pages` set?

Comment: @JohnnyDew, @AlexanderO'Mara I added the query where `$options_pages` is set I tryed adding `'numberposts' => -1` in a few places that seemed to make sence but no go

Comment: you are showing your form submission code above. There is a function either in this class or a parent class. you need to find the function get_all_posts, start in the current file and if not found look for the class the current file extends (you'll see this at the top of the class). If you cant do this you'll need someone to look through your files = hire developer.

Comment: @tim on you just deleted excel question - which I was about to answer: 1) Use `Set` on this line `rLastCellRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"),......` (2) Your test line should be `Application.Goto GetUsedRange("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing the function get_all_post() with the below function.

```
function get_all_post(){

    $options_pages = array();
    $args= array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_type'        => 'post',
    );
    $options_pages_obj = get_posts($args);
    $options_pages[''] = 'Select a Post:';  
    foreach ($options_pages_obj as $page) {
    $options_pages[$page->ID] = $page->post_title;  
    }
    return $options_pages;
}
```